# AWK how to count patterns on the first column?

Tags: awk, gawk

I was trying get the total number of "??", " M", "A" and "D" from this:

```
?? this is a sentence
 M this is another one
A  more text here
D  more and more text
```

I have this sample line of code but doesn't work:

```
 awk -v pattern="\?\?" '{$1 == pattern} END{print " "FNR}'
```

Comment: reasons to check your title before posting, #1

Comment: The proper solution is to use the machine-readable output format from Subversion and parse that.  However, the XML is fairly complex, so you'll find a lot of existing solutions similar to what you tried here.  Did you google at all?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{ print $1 }' file | sort | uniq -c 
1 ??
1 A
1 D
1 M
```

If for some reason you want an awk-only solution:

```
awk '{ ++cnt[$1] } END { for (i in cnt) print cnt[i], i }' file
```

but I think that's needlessly complicated compared to using the built-in unix tools that already do most of the work.

If you just want to count one particular value:

```
awk -v value='??' '$1 == value' file | wc -l
```

If you want to count only a subset of values, you can use a regex:

```
$ awk -v pattern='A|D|(\\?\\?)' '$1 ~ pattern { print $1 }' file | sort | uniq -c
1 ??
1 A
1 D
```

Here you do need to send a `\` in order that the `?`s are escaped within the regular expression. And because the `\` is itself a special character within the string being passed to awk, you need to escape it first (hence the double backslash).